# Google CloudPlatform remove/delete app deployed during tutorial steps

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created a Project at Google CloudPlatform, and followed it's on screen tutorial to deploy an PHP app.

Now that it's done, how can I delete/remove the deployed app to prevent charges.

I saw an option at: "`Google Cloud App Engine -> Settings -> Disable App`" but does it prevent charges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, disabling an application prevents charges, but only from the App Engine prospective, there could still be other changes from other Cloud products usage. From [Disabling an application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/#disabling_an_application):

> Your app's resources in both the standard and flexible environment are
>   disabled and therefore, won't incur charges. However, billing charges
>   can still occur for the other services in your Cloud Platform project,
>   for example you can still incur storage charges for your stored data.

To completely end all Cloud billing for a project you can [shut it down](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/#shutting_down_a_project) (i.e. mark it for deletion!). But please note that you won't be able to re-use its ID, ever.